# Cast a Typescript class to a string?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Typescript interface that I need to convert to a string to send to an API endpoint.

This is the object (as printed from the console using `console.log()`

> {name: "John", avatarId: 1, forwardRelationship: "WIFE",
> reverseRelationship: "HUSBAND"}

I initially tried `JSON.stringify()` to turn it into a string that the API would be happy with which outputs the following:

> {"name":"John","avatarId":1,"forwardRelationship":"WIFE","reverseRelationship":"HUSBAND"}

The API needs just the one string though so:

> "{name:John,avatarId:1,forwardRelationship:WIFE,reverseRelationship:HUSBAND}"

Is there a function I do this with shorthand? Or do Need to build the string up manually using each property?

Comment: Your API requires invalid JSON as input? I would heartily suggest you make it accept *valid* JSON instead.

Comment: I completely agree with @VLAZ here. If you **really** need to send your data like this, you will have to build up the string manually, there is no shorthand for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to change the backend to accept valid JSON.
If you really need to use this format you could use the following method:

```
   const text: string = "\"" + JSON.stringify(yourObject).replace(/"/g,"") + "\"";
```